# How can I make WordPress serve homepage to different URL?

Tags: homepage, frontpage, home-url

I would like to set up a landing page and a homepage for my WordPress website. I am new to WordPress, but I am an experienced web developer.

WordPress will only serve the homepage content if the URL is `example.com`; however, I would like to force it to serve the homepage content to `example.com/home`.

I was planning on setting the “Front Page” to the Landing Page I have created. And then the landing page will link to `example.com/home`. However, for now the `example.com/home` page is blank, and I would like to have it display the “Home Page” content.

Basically, I am trying to find out whether it is possible to make `example.com/home` serve what is supposed to be on the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by creating a new page called "Home" with the permalink slug of "home" and  another page e.g. "Landing" for your landing page. Then go to Settings -> Reading and set the "Front Page" option to your landing page from the dropdown box. You will then be able to link to `mydomain.com/home` from your landing page.

Comment: Hi james, I would appreciate it if you could help me on this THANKS! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/374984/homepage-to-serve-content-from-my-custom-landing-page